# Access F12 key function on keyboard that does not have this key

Tags: keyboard, chef-infra

I have a question related to a bloetooth keyboard I bought, and I would be very grateful if anyone can help me.
This keyboard doesn't have the F12 key, so I was wondering if it's possible to access the same function as the F12 through some shortcut???

Answer (score 0):

The function keys are most likely there...but are not separate. Do you have a manual for the keyboard? Some keys usually perform more than one function and you can access them by pressing them alongside the 'FN' key, 'Shift' key or 'Ctrl' key. So...look through your keyboard for any extra label attached a key's name, some of the keys available can act as function keys when tagged alongside modifier keys.

Comment: thanks for your attention @thePatriarch, but I don't have the keyboard manual, and it also doesn't have any F12 or F11 label on the keys so I could use the FN key together.

Comment: @john-lenon-dos-reis What is the model of the bluetooth keyboard you bought? Like, I'll need the company name and model.